# Is it possible show a tree view in a tooltip in Qt?

Tags: qt

Is it possible show a tree view in a tooltip in Qt? Or represent a tree view with a QString and then show it in a tooltip?

Comment: Is it a QTreeView with model, or QTreeWidget?

Comment: QTreeView with model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

doc states:

> The tip is a short piece of text reminding the user of the widget's function. It is drawn immediately below the given position in a distinctive black-on-yellow color combination. The tip can be any rich text formatted string.
>
> Rich text displayed in a tool tip is implicitly word-wrapped unless specified differently with `<p style='white-space:pre'>.`

Then I would suggest the simplest way could be to use a nested HTML list, something like `<ul><li>...<ul><li>...</ul>...</ul>` that could be easy to get from your structure

Answer (score 1):

I think you need create treeview dynamically and show it when user stop moving mouse.

1. Create widget containing QTreeView and name like ToolTipTree
2. Make TooltipTree to follow mouse
3. When user stop moving mouse, set ToolTipTree shown. I user move mouse again, hide ToolTipTree